# How Can I split the same block into 2 column inside it? Tikzposter

Tags: latex, overleaf

Hi all I would like to split the block in 2 column, in 1 placing an Image and in other the written part. Thank in Advance

```
\documentclass[a2paper,colspace=1pt,blockverticalspace=1pt]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Board}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}


\begin{columns}
\column{0.55} 
\block{\large Scientific Relevance}{
\small The overall \textcolor{red}{why is this outside?mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}}

\column{0.45} \block{Ciao}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach using `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[a2paper,colspace=1pt,blockverticalspace=1pt]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Board}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}


\begin{columns}
\column{0.55} 
\block{\large Scientific Relevance}{
\small The overall \textcolor{red}{why is this outside?mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}}

\column{0.45} \block{Ciao}{%
\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
some text in this column
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For someone who wants to use automatic column breaking in `\block`, He/she can use `multicol` package:
in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{4cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1mm}
```

and

```
\block{Conclusion and outlook}{
   \begin{multicols}{4}
     \lipsum[10-11]
   \end{multicols}
}
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a2paper,colspace=1pt,blockverticalspace=1pt]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Board}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
    
    \node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};
    
    \maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
    \colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
    \colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
    \block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}
    
    
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.55} 
        \block{\large Scientific Relevance}{
            \small The overall \textcolor{red}{why is this outside?mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}}
        
        \column{0.45} \block{Ciao}{%
                \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
                    \lipsum[1]
                \end{multicols}
        }
    \end{columns}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]